# How to skip intro video?

Tags: battlefield-3

The age old question of how do i get right to the action ... NOW. ;)

How do I skip the intro videos?

So far I have been training in the Campaign mode. So I am not sure if online or co-op players have this problem too.

cheers

Comment: Don't have BF3 to try, but the method from 2 was to just move/delete/rename the `.bik` movie files in the `/Movies` folder.

Comment: As a side note, online multiplayer doesn't have any videos (dunno about co-op), you get into the action right away.

Comment: Heck, I didn't even know there *was* an intro video

Comment: I for one want to be able to skip the developer/platform logos that eat 1 minute of my life every time I fire up the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest I know currently on how to skip through the intro.

1. Endure the developer logos.
2. Once you see the Battlefield soldier, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>
3. You then have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see the menu.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes it also works to created dummy/empty files
So, rename the old ones to .bak or something
Then create an empty file with the same name

(no guarantees given as I don't have BF3!)

Comment: Dummy files of *what*? As it stands, this is pretty useless. It seems the videos are buried in other archive files in a proprietary format, so simply replacing/deleting them is not even possible.

Comment: In BF2 they used to give a "consistency error" for removing/replacing the files with the intro movies when I played it. They use the same mechanizm that checks if You didn't switch the soldier textures to red etc.

Comment: This is a solution that has worked with a lot of games in the past.  It may not work with BF3, but I don't think you need to be so harsh.